# Django admin - property options based on a related parent model

Tags: django, design-patterns, django-admin, mixins

I have a parent and a child class. The relation between them is many-to-one like this:

```
class Parent(AccessmanagerMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class Child(AccessmanagerMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    parent_group = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True )
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

they both have a many-to-many relation with the User class, named read_users (its a custom security on object level).

```
class AccessmanagerMixin(models.Model):
    read_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='read_users')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

For example in the admin I would like to use the users from Parent read_users as an option for selecting the read_users for the Child entity? How can I do this in a best way?  Can I
override the read_users property in the Child admin.ModelAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define which values are shown for a many-to-many field on the admin site with the `formfield_for_manytomany()` method.

Example for showing a union of the Parent's read_users for Child objects:

```py
class ChildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "read_users":
            kwargs["queryset"] = User.objects.filter(pk__in=(list(Parent.objects.values_list("read_users__pk", flat=True))))
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

See official Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Erik , interesting solution, I will try it out.  I was planning to solve it by using get and setters on the property of the Child class.

Comment: It's part of the Django API for the admin site. It has a lot of useful features, but it takes a while to get to know them all.

Comment: yea that's true :)

Comment: Erik,  I think there is one flaw with this approach, if the admin deletes the user from the read_users at the Parent class, while the user is being attached to Child read_users. The user will be inside the Child read_users and will not get displayed at the admin portal.

Comment: True. I did not fully understand from your question which users you want to show exactly, so was just showing the approach. Should be easy to adapt the query to your needs though. e.g. make a union of users from both Child and Parent.